# When using sudo in Jenkins pipline sh command, it always asks for inputing password even I've set sudoers to NOPASSWD

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running Jenkins 2.319.2 installed from Debian Bullseye repository and set up some nodes to run my tasks.

In my Jenkins pipeline task, which is running on a node instead of on the master node, I set up several stages, including checkout, build, deploy and finally I have to restart a system service using `systemctl`.  The last step needs to be run with root privileges, so I set up the running user on the node in sudoers config to let it run systemctl without password (`NOPASSWD`).  However, my task **always** asks for password when running the final step, and hence fails.

If I directly log in the user with ssh, I can run `sudo systemctl` without needing to input password.  In my other freestyle task, I also used the same way to run `sudo systemctl restart myservice` in the "execute shell", without any problem.  But in the pipeline stage it always asks for password.  No idea why.

Comment: Please paste the command you tried in the sudoers config to give the NOPASSWD permission

Comment: @SouravAtta I didn't touch the original /etc/sudoers config.  I added a file under /etc/sudoers.d/ named /etc/sudoers.d/super, with content: `%super   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`.  Then I added the users responsible for deploying and restarting the system into the group `super`.  When logging in that user I could run any command using sudo without having to input the password.